# Proof that the Matrix-Exponential is continuous by using Weierstrass M-Test

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I am currently reading the book *Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations An Elementary Introduction* by Brian C. Hall and I have a question regarding the proof of the continuity of the exponential of a matrix.

In Proposition 2.1 which is about the continuity of the matrix-exponential the author states:

> To show continuity, note that since $X^m$ is a continuous function of $X$, the partial
> sums of [the matrix exponential] are continuous. By the Weierstrass M-test, the series [of the matrix exponential] converges uniformly on each set of the form $\{\|X\| \leq R\}$. Thus, $e^X$ is continuous on each such set, and, thus, continuous on all of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.

I am familiar with some proofs that are using the inequality $\left\| e^{X+Y} - e^X\right\| \le \|Y\| e^{\|X\|} e^{\|Y\|}$. But because of the fact that these proofs are rather long, I would find it interesting to see if the following short proof is correct:

Let $M_n = \frac{R^n}{n!}$. Then it is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty M_n = e^R < \infty$. At the same time it is $\|X\| \leq R$ and therefore $\|\frac{X^n}{n!}\| = \frac{\|X^n\|}{n!} \leq \frac{\|X\|^n}{n!}\leq \frac{R^n}{n!}$. Then using the Weierstrass M-test we know that the series converges uniformly on these sets and therefore the matrix-exponential is continuous.

I would really appreciate it, if You could give me Your opinion on this.

Comment: It is not $\left\|\frac{X^n}{n!}\right\|$ that needs to be bounded above here, but rather $\left\|\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{X^k}{k!}\right\|$.

Comment: As long as you’ve proven a sufficiently general version of the Weierstrass M-test (whose proof is essentially a repeat of the basic version for real numbers) then yes what you did is fine.

Comment: @Math1000 that’s why the Weierstrass M-test exists: it gives a simple sufficient condition to verify uniform convergence.

Comment: Hmm, seems that the proximity of "partial sums" and "Weierstrass M-test" in the quoted text mixed me up a bit. Indeed, here the partial sums are not relevant to the Weierstrass M-test, but rather to the uniform limit theorem. My mistake.